# convenient practice to write/display help/usage info in a program written in C?

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C which is like a console so that user can specify different commands to be executed(which are also defined by me). Just like the one below:

```
>cmd1 arg
(result blah blah blah)
>
```

and I want to display usage info which is like:

```
>help
Usage: cmd1 arg1 [arg2]
       cmd2 arg1 [arg2]
       cmd3 arg1 [arg2]
       ....
```

But I find it clumsy to define string or macro like `"Usage: cmd1 arg1 [arg2] \n \t "...` (and I am not sure it's OK or not).
Is there some best practice to do so?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall well, i forget to add. thx

Comment: No problem, making a shell like this is just a very typical CS assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard practice is to make a `usage` function that you can call when certain conditions are met (there were no arguments pass to the program, etc), like this:

```
void usage(void) {
    printf("Usage: cmd1 arg1 [arg2]\n"
           "       cmd2 arg1 [arg2]\n"
           "       cmd3 arg1 [arg2]\n"
           ...
           "       cmdn arg1 [arg2]\n"); // if the string is too long you'll have
                                         // to break it up into multiple printfs
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        usage(); 
        return 0;
    }

    // main program....
}
```

Comment: It's also probably noteworthy that strings can be concatenated in C simply by putting double-quoted strings next to each other, separated by only whitespace. Can be handy for very long strings like this.

Comment: I can't remember the exact limit, but a conforming C implementation must allow for strings of *at least* 4096 characters in length. Some compilers may allow for more, but 4096 is the safe limit (or whatever it is as defined in the C standard).

Comment: @dreamlax A quick perusal of the C99 spec and I couldn't find anything in reference to this. Though to be honest it seems odd for there to be any limit, since it's just a string of characters, which shouldn't be much different than the ability to store 4096 individual `char`s (assuming that 4096 includes `\0`).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Perhaps I misread, but see 5.2.4.1: " 4095 characters in a character string literal or wide string literal (after concatenation"

Comment: @dreamlax Of course, I'd looked at the page *after* that one but not that one itself; thanks for pointing it out! I assume that's 4095 plus the null character.

Answer (score 1):

If you're programming on/for a system that can use the [gnu argp library](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Argp.html),  you'd do well to look into that.  It makes it easier to process the arguments, and creates help/usage messages and options for you.